# PHP - how to read recursive children of children from XML and display it correctly?

Tags: php, xml, recursion, simplexml, children

I'm connecting to a system that is providing me a list of users, the data is to be displayed in a 'tree format' so you can see the parent / child relationships, its almost like a reseller tree..

Cannot work out how to recursively go through the XML, retrieve Parent ID's and record the Child ID records. Problem is some Child IDs can be Parent IDs as well.

I also am not sure how I can directly access a certain UserID from the XML as each record only consists of attributes.

I've uploaded a sample copy of the XML to the following URL : 
http://www.fluffyduck.com.au/sampleXML.txt

I'm trying to do this with SimpleXML, however I cannot work out how to loop down through children of children it almost seems like.

Any help appreciated! as this has me completely stumped.

Comment: you may tag your question "recursion" too... because that's the best solution to find your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an array of parents / children, you may use :

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('http://www.fluffyduck.com.au/sampleXML.txt');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

$users = array ();
myUserReader($xml->user, $users);

function myUserReader($node, &$users)
{
    if (array_key_exists("{$node['id']}", $users) === false)
    {
        $users["{$node['id']}"] = array ();
    }
    if (isset($node->user))
    {
        for ($key = 0; ($key < $node->user->count()); $key++)
        {
            $user = $node->user[$key];
            if (!in_array("{$node['id']}", $users["{$node['id']}"]))
            {
                $users["{$node['id']}"][] = "{$user['id']}";
            }
            myUserReader($user, $users);
        }
    }
}

foreach ($users as $parent => $children)
{
    echo "{$parent}: " . implode(", ", $children) . "\n";
}
?>
```

This will output :

```
41: 61, 62, 69, 89, 127, 204, 323, 340, 341
61: 
62: 64, 78, 80, 116, 120
64: 66
66: 67
67: 68, 114, 161, 162, 166, 203
68: 70
70: 72, 77, 104, 118, 135, 138, 143, 154, 156, 171, 172, 173, 174
72: 73, 86, 163, 165, 167
73: 75
75: 
86: 92, 103, 108, 112, 117, 119, 121, 124, 125, 137, 144
92: 107, 110, 111, 142
107: 
110: 
111: 
142: 
103: 
108: 
112: 
117: 
119: 
121: 
124: 
125: 
137: 
144: 
163: 
165: 
167: 
77: 79, 113
79: 
113: 
104: 106
106: 
118: 
135: 
138: 
143: 
154: 
156: 
171: 
172: 
173: 
174: 
114: 
161: 
162: 
166: 169, 175, 176, 178, 179, 180, 183, 184, 205, 206
169: 
175: 
176: 
178: 
179: 
180: 
183: 
184: 
205: 
206: 
203: 
78: 136
136: 
80: 101
101: 
116: 122, 126, 129, 130, 131, 133, 139, 140, 141
122: 
126: 
129: 
130: 
131: 
133: 
139: 
140: 
141: 
120: 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 157, 160, 168
145: 
146: 
147: 
148: 
149: 
150: 152, 153, 155, 159
152: 
153: 
155: 
159: 
151: 
157: 
160: 
168: 
69: 
89: 
127: 
204: 207
207: 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 227, 254, 300
208: 213, 214, 215, 226, 228, 234, 255, 294, 295, 297, 299, 320
213: 
214: 
215: 
226: 
228: 
234: 
255: 274, 275
274: 
275: 
294: 
295: 
297: 
299: 
320: 
209: 
210: 217, 218, 222
217: 
218: 
222: 
211: 
212: 
227: 
254: 
300: 
323: 
340: 
341:
```

Comment: I checked your code with foreach... and there is no inf. loop. I even check with adding parameter $i to function to check number of sub-item.. still only 5 deeper calls.

Comment: Thanks, very strange. I have an infinite loop on the last elem. I'll check it tonight.

Comment: Hi Ninsuo, this is the closest i've seen to solving this problem, however it does not show the recursive ID's, there was 147 userID's but not all displayed above. For example, ID#62 has a child #64, which has a child #66, which has a child #67, which has a child #67, which has a child #68, which has child #70 and then #72, then #73 finish with #75. That is one of the tree's, I'm not sure if it is malformed xml it displays fine with Flash code but i'm not fluent in flash :(

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I wrote it quickly because I needed to get at work :p Let see it closer now.

Comment: That's OK, I updated my answer. I made a mistake on my recursion (I jumped all parents, so there were only children who had children too).

Comment: that is great!! my problem now is, I dont know how to access those children. Based on your code there, I thought I would simply load the user ID and retrieve the data from the XML to put it in the format you listed, however thats not working. I thought perhaps I could somehow pull the information from your code that originally that listed all the users in a basic 2 dimensional array, however that function has duplicate information for some reason and missing others, this is proving to be a lot more difficult that I had anticipated, thank you so much for your help so far! it is much appreciated

Comment: This array gives you a list of parent ids with their list of children. There is no duplicate? Gives me 2 parents where you'll find the same children? If you want to retrieve an array of parent ids with a list of children nodes, you can replace `$users["{$node['id']}"][] = "{$user['id']}";` by `$users["{$node['id']}"][] = $user;`.

Comment: Hi Ninsuo, I did that modification just now as a test to view just the parents, but children are still being displayed for example ID - "156" is a child of ID#70.. The duplicate issue I was referring to the example above where you used 'array_merge', basically my problem is now that you have almost solved displaying parent/child, is How can I retrieve certain records from either array or xml to pull the records out, I thought perhaps somehow putting them in 2 dimensional array where i can search for ID and retreive array location might work? but I'm unsure how to construct the array for that

Comment: I don't get it. 156 is a child of #id70 this is true ! `<user id="156" username="EvolutionSystems" firstname="Steven" lastname="MyTest" fullname="Test Name" email="lalal@test.com" logins="10" lastseen="29/11/2010"/>` is on the #70 id's scope isn't it? parent 66 has children 67, parent 67 has children 68, ... What do you want? This is not a duplicate, because children may be parents themselves. I do not know what you want finally, give me a pastebin where you write a fake var_dump of data you expect and I'll be able to take it. I spent a lot of time on your case already.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far!! it is extrmeely appreciated, I thought with your last bit of code meant that only parents would displayed, which is why I questioned ID 156 as its a child only.

Comment: Last problem is don't know how to access specific ID out of the xml so I can display data tree based off the code you created, since they are all <user> tags in a wierd heirachy, you did code originally like :    foreach ($node as $user)
    {
        $users[] = $user->attributes();
        if (isset($user->user))
        {
            $users = array_merge($users, myUserReader($user->user));
        }
    }
    return $users; but it did not show all users and some duplicates.

I thought from that array I could search ID, find array key, and display full user details based on your other code.

Comment: So if I understand, you do want to have a function to find a node, and return it with all its info+children?

Comment: Correct, with your method of parent/child, I can use the ID's from that function, to try create a table that will display parent + children underneath. Problem now is I do not know how to access those ID's directly to retrieve their information

Comment: OK. I will create a third answer to your question here in such way. Next time, please be very precise when asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, can't add an answer, i create a pastebin then: find it [here](http://pastebin.com/r2BLVQJ8)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'm sorry I did not know how to word my question, I thought I had asked the question correctly.. thakn you for your help, I wont bother you with anymore and will try work the rest out

Answer (score 1):

This work and returns an array of 147 SimpleXMLElement (usable like arrays).

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.fluffyduck.com.au/sampleXML.txt');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$users = myUserReader($xml->user);

function myUserReader($node)
{
    $users = array ();
    $users[] = $node->attributes();
    foreach ($node as $user)
    {
        $users[] = $user->attributes();
        if (isset($user->user))
        {
            $users = array_merge($users, myUserReader($user->user));
        }
    }
    return $users;
}

// displays 147 children
var_dump($users);

// displays 147
echo count($users);
```

Comment: Hi Ninsuo, This is great, it pulls all the users, however I'm not sure how to retain the parent/child relationship within the data.

There are a series of 'parent users' which have a subtree of children users and some go further down the tree again.

I need to try retain the layout. for example.

UserID = 41 is parent to all, then UserID 62 for example has a bunch of users that fall under that single user, this has me stuck

Comment: Simple : do not save attributes but save the whole node. This will not take a lot of memory because objects are stored as reference. Replace `$users[] = $node->attributes();` and `$users[] = $user->attributes();` by `$users[] = $node;` and `$users[] = $user;`.

Comment: ahh yes of course, sorry I was not clear with my problem.

What I can't work out, is how do I display those children users appropriately, I can display them fine as if they were all individual (parent) records, however I dont know how to display child of a child etc.

It's almost as if it could be an infinite loop to scale down to check if another child exists and then display that under the previous child (if exists). Since I"m told there's no real limit as to how far it could scale down in future. I hope i'm making some sense to the problem.

Comment: a yeah, I actually reproduce your problem. Strange in fact! Will get around this.

Comment: answered above. I found a solution and know the way to reproduce it but have no explaination :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);
$user = $xml->user;

while($curr_user = $curr_user->children('user'))
{
    // do some code
    $attr = array(
        $curr_user['id'],
        $curr_user['username'],
        $curr_user['firstname'],
        // ...etc
        );
}
```

So it's only example of usage and finding child nodes. To walk through all array u can user recursive function like this code.

EDIT:
Sry for copying Ninsuo code, but it is perfect one :)

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.fluffyduck.com.au/sampleXML.txt');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$users = myUserReader($xml->user);

function myUserReader($node,$str)
{
    $users = array ();
    $users[] = $node->attributes();
    foreach ($node as $user)
    {
        $users[] = $user->attributes();
        if (isset($user->user))
        {
            $str .= '<ul>'.$user['fisrt_name'];
            $users = array_merge($users, myUserReader($user->user));
            $str .= '</ul>';
        }
        else $str .= '<li>'.$user['fisrt_name'].'</li>';
    }
    return $users,$str;
}
```

Comment: for example like this.. (i dont check this for working good, it's only concept and idea how it must be): http://pastebin.com/VQaMdiSP

Comment: This is very similar to Ninsuo code below, however I'm still unfortunately experiencing the problem, where I cannot display the data in a 'tree' type format where I can show which users are 'children' of others due to it being so many levels cascading down.

If you view the sample xml you will see what I mean, I just cant work it out.

Comment: Ninsuo code is better, indeed. He wrote working code, but I give oly example "how to".